# Core Data prefetching not working for certain relationship

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm executing a fetch request on a MessageObject and prefetching the following:

```
[fetchRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:
   [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tags", @"date", nil]];
```

Tags is a many-to-many relationship (that is, a Tag can have many Messages, and a Message can have many tags), while Date is a to-one relationship (that is, a Message can only have one Date while a Date can have many Messages).

As I scroll down my table, I access both Tags and Date. I have SQLite debugging enabled, so every time Core Data executes a fault request, it appears in the log. For some reason, the Date property is not being prefetched, since every time I scroll, I get `CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0x85bc7b0 <x-coredata://736D04C4-7DB3-40B7-B208-79B5DFD68260/MBDate/p61>`

However, this does not appear for the Tags, only date. If I don't prefetch the Tags property, then that same message appears for Tags when I scroll, so I know the prefetch is working, just not for the Date property.

Is there something I'm not understanding about prefetching? A Date object has a string property, and in my cellForRow, I access this string property, which for some reason causes the fault to fire (even though it should have been realized already since it was prefetched.) Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: How accurate is your date? If it is down to a second, you might be better off not using a relationship, but an `NSDate` property/attribute.

Comment: Well I need it as a relationship so that my Date object can have multiple Message objects. An NSDate won't do

Comment: So I guess it excludes hours, minutes and seconds? You can still get to multiple messages with a predicate.